# How to add a 'Stop Macro' in excel-vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple macro and a button to start running it. I would like to also have a button to stop it, so I don't have to have the vba editor open to do it.

Here's the code.

```
Sub Data_Recording()

    With Workbooks("Chart_Macro").Sheets("Chart")
        .Rows(5).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, 
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("B5:F5").Value = .Range("B2:F2").Value
    End With

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "Data_Recording"

    End Sub
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Armando suggests, you can use this code:

```
Sub Data_Recording()

    With Workbooks("Chart_Macro").Sheets("Chart")
        If .Range(CHECK_ADDRESS) = True Then Exit Sub
        .Rows(5).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown,
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("B5:F5").Value = .Range("B2:F2").Value
    End With

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "Data_Recording"

End Sub

Public Sub SetRecordingState(bStop As Boolean)

    Workbooks("Chart_Macro").Sheets("Chart").Range(CHECK_ADDRESS) = bStop

End Sub
```

So I've added one line to your code that checks the value. And you can change the state using the other sub. If the State is set to True, the procedure will stop

Comment: What value is it checking? How can it know it's true?. Thanks

Comment: The value in the cell specified as CHECK_ADDRESS. This can be any cell. E.g. declare it at module level as `    Private Const CHECK_ADDRESS As String = "$A$1"
`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an idea could be that on each iteration the macro could check the value of one variable or even a hidden/protected cell, and another macro or button could change that value, so if its 'stop' the macro could exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the Schedule parameter of Application.OnTime to stop the next call of the macro? You will need to save the time in a global variable to do so.

```
Dim NextTime As Date
Sub Data_Recording()
    Debug.Print "Data recorded at : " & Now
    NextTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime NextTime, "Data_Recording"
End Sub

Sub Stop_Recording()
    Application.OnTime NextTime, Procedure:="Data_Recording", Schedule:=False
    Debug.Print "Recording stopped at : " & Now
End Sub
```